# Input Stream from ZipResourceFile talking lot of time to read data

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have successfully implemented Apk Expansion Files for my project.

Problem:In my .obb i have a folder which has 100 xml files in it.Now the problem is i am using the below code to read the data directly from .obb files without extracting the data.

this is code given in the offical doc here http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html under the topic Reading from a ZIP file

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(MyActivity.this, 1, 0);
String pathToFileInsideZip = "main.1.com.my.expansionfiles.obb/data/" +filename;
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

i have a `for loop` in that i am calling writing this code so that it will read all the xml one by one and make the data ready for me to display.

The above will read the data directly from .obb file, but the problem is its talking lot of time to extract the data?

Why so? i am doing any mistake here?

Comment: The mistake is almost certainly in the code you didn't post, the part that actually does the I/O you describe.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the reply but why is it talking time to read?

Answer (score 0):

I believed that the **pathToFileInsideZip** would not be

> main.1.com.my.expansionfiles.obb/data/[files].

I think it's just

> "data/[files]"